# ReactJS - pushing to a list outside of a promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise

I want to update a list which is defined outside of a promise (API call).

here is the code:

```
let data = [];
  api.getData(this.state.ID).then((resp) => {
    data = [...data, { title : resp.title }];
    data = [...data, { name :  resp.name }];
  });
  console.log(data); // --> it returns []
```

the data is [ ] and no value have pushed to it. how can I change my code to fix this issue? for some reasons I don't want to use `setState()`

Regards.

Comment: if this is exactly the order in which the code it written , it will return [ ] only, as the api.getData is async.!

Comment: Ultimately, you want to render this data, correct? Heed the advice from others to solve the problem at hand, but based on how you're writing it, it can't be done without `this.setState`. I am assuming you are not using redux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

Promise is **ALWAYS** asynchronous, meaning that your data array will still be empty after you define the promise.

To get access to filled data array you have to refer to it inside the promise.

```
let data = [];

api.getData(this.state.ID).then((resp) => {
    data = [...data, { title: resp.title }, { name: resp.name }];

    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `console.log` function is getting executed before api returns you data. Although data got updated after api call. You could not see it because it is consoled before that.

```
let data = [];
  api.getData(this.state.ID).then((resp) => {
    data = [...data, { title : resp.title }];
    data = [...data, { name :  resp.name }];
    Console.log(data)
})
```

Now you can see data consoles.

But if you want to console the data after then method then you can make the execution of api synchronized by using npm module `q`.

Answer (score 1):

Async/Await will help you:

```
let data = [];
async function getData() {
  await api.getData(this.state.ID).then((resp) => {
    data = [...data, { title : resp.title }];
    data = [...data, { name :  resp.name }];
  });
  console.log(data); // --> it shouldn't return empty array
}
getData();
```

Example:

```js
    function resolveAfter2Seconds(x) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve("You see it after promis end");
        }, 2000);
      });
    }
    
    
    var arr = [];
    async function f1() {
      await resolveAfter2Seconds(10).then(res => arr.push(res));
      alert(arr);
    }
    f1();
```